# Add a new key value pair to an arraylist

Tags: groovy

I have 2 ArrayLists. One is [[Account:value,Budget:value]] and the other is [[Account:value,cYBudget:value]]  I want to end up with a list in the following format: [[Account:value,Budget:value, cYBudget:value]]

An example of the data is:

budProp = [[ACCTCODE:6201, BUDGET:2500], [ACCTCODE:7999, BUDGET:1500]]

budCyExp = [[ACCTCODE:6201,cYBudget:1000],[ACCTCODE:7999,cYBudget: 2000]]

I'd like a result of:

[[ACCTCODE:6201,BUDGET: 2500, cYBudget:1000],[ACCTCODE:7999,BUDGET:1500,cYBudget: 2000]]

Basically I am "merging" the two lists by matching ACCTCODE and assuring that each list contains an ACCTCODE, BUDGET and cYBudget key/value pair.  Does Groovy has some method to do this?

I am using Groovy 2.3.7

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method [GroovyCollections#transpose()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.7/html/gapi/groovy/util/GroovyCollections.html#transpose(java.util.List)) can generate a list of pairs from two lists:

```
groovy:000> [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]].transpose()
===> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

If you have two lists with the same account codes in the same order, you can zip the parallel list entries into pairs of maps with the transpose method, then merge each pair of maps:

```
[budProp, budCyExp].transpose().collect { it[0] + it[1] }
```

Here are the steps broken out in groovysh so you can see the result of transposing separately:

```
groovy:000> budProp = [[ACCTCODE:6201, BUDGET:2500], [ACCTCODE:7999, BUDGET:1500]]
===> [[ACCTCODE:6201, BUDGET:2500], [ACCTCODE:7999, BUDGET:1500]]
groovy:000> budCyExp = [[ACCTCODE:6201,cYBudget:1000],[ACCTCODE:7999,cYBudget: 2000]]
===> [[ACCTCODE:6201, cYBudget:1000], [ACCTCODE:7999, cYBudget:2000]]
groovy:000> [budProp, budCyExp].transpose()
===> [[[ACCTCODE:6201, BUDGET:2500], [ACCTCODE:6201, cYBudget:1000]], [[ACCTCODE:7999, BUDGET:1500], [ACCTCODE:7999, cYBudget:2000]]]
groovy:000> _.collect { it[0] + it[1] }
===> [[ACCTCODE:6201, BUDGET:2500, cYBudget:1000], [ACCTCODE:7999, BUDGET:1500, cYBudget:2000]]
```

In real life I would be hesitant to use this unless I had 100% certainty that the parallel lists would line up perfectly (every account code in one list is represented in the other), otherwise I'd do something like:

```
groovy:000> budMap = budProp.inject([:]) { m, e -> m[e['ACCTCODE']] = e['BUDGET']; m }
===> [6201:2500, 7999:1500]
groovy:000> cyMap = budCyExp.inject([:]) { m, e -> m[e['ACCTCODE']] = e['cYBudget']; m }
===> [6201:1000, 7999:2000]
groovy:000> (budMap.keySet() + cyMap.keySet()).collect { [ACCTCODE: it, BUDGET: budMap[it], cYBudget: cyMap[it] ] }
===> [[ACCTCODE:6201, BUDGET:2500, cYBudget:1000], [ACCTCODE:7999, BUDGET:1500,
cYBudget:2000]]
```

This isn't as short but it handles the case where an account from one list is not represented in the other.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That is exactly what I needed.  You are right about the lists not lining up perfectly, they don't, but I figured an answer would point me in the right direction and I'd have to figure out the rest, but you gave me exactly what I needed for all of it.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where the lists do not line up perfectly, it would be more appropriate to use the Groovy [Iterable.groupBy(Closure)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.0/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#groupBy(groovy.lang.Closure)) method:

```
def budProp = [[ACCTCODE:6201, BUDGET:2500], [ACCTCODE:7999, BUDGET:1500]]
def budCyExp = [[ACCTCODE:7999,cYBudget: 2000], [ACCTCODE:6201,cYBudget:1000]]

def budMaster = (budProp + budCyExp)
println budMaster
//[[ACCTCODE:6201, BUDGET:2500], [ACCTCODE:7999, BUDGET:1500], [ACCTCODE:7999, cYBudget:2000], [ACCTCODE:6201, cYBudget:1000]]

def budMappedAcct = budMaster.groupBy { it.ACCTCODE }
println budMappedAcct
// [6201:[[ACCTCODE:6201, BUDGET:2500], [ACCTCODE:6201, cYBudget:1000]], 7999:[[ACCTCODE:7999, BUDGET:1500], [ACCTCODE:7999, cYBudget:2000]]]

def budMapList = budMappedAcct.collect { code, mapList -> mapList.sum() }
println budMapList
// [[ACCTCODE:6201, BUDGET:2500, cYBudget:1000], [ACCTCODE:7999, BUDGET:1500, cYBudget:2000]]
```

This works for out-of order and mismatched lists too, as long as all the original maps have an `ACCTCODE`. If desired this solution can be condensed down to a one-liner:

```
def budMapList = (budProp + budCyExp).groupBy { it.ACCTCODE }.collect { code, mapList -> mapList.sum() }
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer as well, I like having multiple solutions to a problem, it helps me learn more.  The only thing that makes Nathan's solution more applicable is that it will return an ACCTCODE, BUDGET and cYBudget regardless of whether ACCTCODE value is in both lists.  For example, budProp may have a 3rd set of ACCTCODE and BUDGET that doesn't exist in budCyExp, so it will return [ACCTCODE:value, BUDGET:value, cYBudget:null].  I don't have enough reputation points to mark your answer as useful yet, but I would if I could.

Comment: Don't sweat the points; I'm not really here for the points. Besides, if someone else likes the answer, they'll give it a bump. Java/Groovy default map semantics ensure that if you request an item from a map for which there isn't a key, the map will return null. So even thought the entry `cYBudget: null` would not be explicitly defined in the map if you were to attempt to access the key anyway, the result would be null: `answerMap.cYBudget == null `. So from a data access point of view the result is the same.